# Initializing a std::unique_ptr by passing the address of the pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am creating a class which interops with some Windows API code, now one of the pointers I have to initialize is done by calling a native function which initializes it.

My pointers are of type `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter, which calls the WinAPI deleter function provided, however I cannot pass the unique_ptr with the & address-of operator to the init-function. Why?

I have created a sample that demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <memory>

struct foo
{
   int x;
};

struct custom_deleter {};

void init_foo(foo** init)
{
  *init = new foo();
}

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<foo, custom_deleter> foo_ptr;

   init_foo(&foo_ptr);
}
```

The compiler barks and says:

```
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:19:21: error: cannot convert 'std::unique_ptr<foo, custom_deleter>*' to 'foo**' for argument '1' to 'void init_foo(foo**)'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Somewhere under the covers, `unique_ptr<foo>` has a data member of type `foo*`.

However, it's not legitimate for a user of the class to directly modify that data member. Doing so would not necessarily preserve the class invariants of `unique_ptr`, in particular it wouldn't free the old pointer value (if any). In your special case you don't need that to happen, because the previous value is 0, but in general it should happen.

For that reason `unique_ptr` doesn't provide access to the data member, only to a copy of its value (via `get()` and `operator->`). You can't get a `foo**` out of your `unique_ptr`.

You could instead write:

```
foo *tmp;
init_foo(&tmp);
std::unique_ptr<foo, custom_deleter> foo_ptr(tmp);
```

This is exception-safe for the same reason that `std::unique_ptr<foo, custom_deleter> foo_ptr(new foo());` is exception-safe: `unique_ptr` guarantees that whatever you pass in to its constructor will eventually get deleted using the deleter.

Btw, doesn't `custom_deleter` need an `operator()(foo*)`? Or have I missed something?

Comment: @ForEverR: what about it? It returns the *value* of that data member, not a pointer to that data member.

Comment: @Tony: `shared_ptr` is the same as `unique_ptr`. If you need to use an interface like `init_foo` that deals in raw pointers, then yes, you need to use raw pointers. Then you put the raw pointer into a suitable smart pointer as soon as possible.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks :) Makes sense.  Now, you're right, it does need the `operator()(foo*)`.  My example is incomplete in that respect

Answer (score 7):

Steve has already explained what the technical problem is, however, the underlying problem goes much deeper: The code employs an idiom helpful when you deal with naked pointers. Why does this code do two-step initialization (first create the object, then initialize it) in the first place? Since you want to use smart pointers, I'd suggest you carefully adapt the code:

```
foo* init_foo()
{
  return new foo();
}

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<foo, custom_deleter> foo_ptr( init_foo() );

}
```

Of course, renaming `init_foo()` to `create_foo()` and having it return a `std::unique_ptr<foo>` directly would be better. Also, when you use two-step initialization, it's often advisable to consider using a class to wrap the data.

Comment: seeing that my `init_foo` is a windows API call, I cannot change it.  So do you suggest I write a wrapper around that function?  Why though? Exception safety is not a problem per @SteveJessop.

Comment: @Tony: sbi's code is just "cleaner", the single line in `main` does what it says. My code needs a temp variable in order to create the thing you actually want. That's not preferable, my code is just what you have to do to call `init_foo` as it was.

Comment: @SteveJessop: "...and having it return a `std::unique_ptr<foo>` directly would be better."

Comment: @sbi: yeah, that! Although the deleter type is part of the `unique_ptr` type, and I don't think the questioner *really* allocates with `new`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I took the `new` from the OP and left out the deleter as a concession to my laziness. `:-/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick:

```
template<class T>
class ptr_setter
{
public:
    ptr_setter(T& Ptr): m_Ptr{Ptr} {}
    ~ptr_setter() { m_Ptr.reset(m_RawPtr); }

    ptr_setter(const ptr_setter&) = delete;
    ptr_setter& operator=(const ptr_setter&) = delete;

    auto operator&() { return &m_RawPtr; }

private:
    T& m_Ptr;
    typename T::pointer m_RawPtr{};
};


// Macro will not be needed with C++17 class template deduction.
// If you dislike macros (as all normal people should)
// it's possible to replace it with a helper function,
// although this would make the code a little more complex.

#define ptr_setter(ptr) ptr_setter<decltype(ptr)>(ptr)
```

and then:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo, custom_deleter> foo_ptr;
init_foo(&ptr_setter(foo_ptr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually came up with an approach that allows to initialise unique_ptr's with a code like this:

```
struct TOpenSSLDeleter { ... }; // Your custom deleter
std::unique_ptr<EVP_MD_CTX, TOpenSSLDeleter> Ctx;
...
Ctx = MakeUnique(EVP_MD_CTX_create()); // MakeUnique() accepts raw pointer
```

And here is the solution:

```
template <class X>
struct TUniquePtrInitHelper {
   TUniquePtrInitHelper(X *Raw) noexcept {
      m_Raw = Raw;
   }
   template <class T, class D>
   operator std::unique_ptr<T, D>() const noexcept {
      return std::unique_ptr<T, D>(m_Raw);
   }

private:
   X *m_Raw;
};
template <class X>
TUniquePtrInitHelper<X> MakeUnique(X *Raw) noexcept {
   return {Raw};
}
```